# C++ vector resize

Tags: c++, vector, resize

There is one exercise i keep getting stuck on and it's the folowing :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 const int PAGE_SIZE = 4;
 vector<int> sizes = {3, 6, 8, 11, 0, 15, 9};

 vector<int> v;
 cout << v.size() << endl;
 for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); i++ ){
   int pages = sizes.at(i) / PAGE_SIZE;
   if ( sizes.at(i) % PAGE_SIZE ) pages++;
   v.resize( pages * PAGE_SIZE );
   cout << v.size() << endl;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

For the above program, bring the numbers being printed in the right order!

The answer to this question and the right order is :

```
0
4
8
8
12
0
16
12
```

I have been trying to work it out but do not quite understand the if statement in combination with the modulo operator. Can someone help and explain this to me?

Comment: You don't need anyone to explain this to you. It's your debugger that can explain everything to you. Did you know that your debugger can show you how your program runs, one line at a time, how all the variables change, what their values are, at any given point, and you can even set breakpoints on condition to be triggered when they occur? Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is something that every C++ developer must learn, and this looks like an excellent opportunity for you to do so! Knowing how to use a debugger means that you never have to ask anyone to help you with your code.

Comment: If you are asking about the meaning of  `int pages = sizes.at(i) / PAGE_SIZE; if ( sizes.at(i) % PAGE_SIZE ) pages++;`, this computes `sizes.at(i)` divided by `PAGE_SIZE`, rounded up. Plain division `/` gives the answer rounded down (truncated towards zero, to be precise), then this answer is increased by one unless `sizes.at(i)` is evenly divisible by `PAGE_SIZE`.

Comment: If you are asking about `v.resize( pages * PAGE_SIZE ); cout << v.size() << endl;`, that's just a really perverse way of implementing `cout << pages * PAGE_SIZE`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help

```
size = 4, size/4 = 1, size%4 = 0, pages = 1
size = 5, size/4 = 1, size%4 = 1, pages = 2
size = 6, size/4 = 1, size%4 = 2, pages = 2
size = 7, size/4 = 1, size%4 = 3, pages = 2
size = 8, size/4 = 2, size%4 = 0, pages = 2
```

Compare the second and fourth columns, When size == 4 or 8 `size/4` equals `pages`. But when size equals 5, 6 or 7 we have to add one to `size/4` to get the value of `pages`. In other words sometimes we need to add one, to round up size/4 to the value of pages we want. Those rows were we have to round up are exactly those rows where `size%4` does not equal zero. That explains the line

```
if ( sizes.at(i) % PAGE_SIZE ) pages++;
```

Answer (score 1):

So in C++, `bool` is "just a kind of integer", namely one that can be either 0 or 1.

And `if(number)` tests if the number is non-zero.

So `if ( a % b)` is `if ( (a%b)!=0 )`.  `a` mod `b` is non-zero when `a` is not an integer multiple of `b`.

```
 int pages = sizes.at(i) / PAGE_SIZE;
 if ( sizes.at(i) % PAGE_SIZE ) pages++;
```

So what this is doinf us calculating `sizes.at(i)` divided by `PAGE_SIZE` then rounding up.

A cleaner way is

```
 int pages = (sizes.at(i)+PAGE_SIZE-1) / PAGE_SIZE;
```

Answer (score 1):

It basically describes the behavior of the ceiling operation (always round up) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int PAGE_SIZE = 4;
    vector<int> sizes = {3, 6, 8, 11, 0, 15, 9};
    // The vector v has size 0
    vector<int> v;
    
    // Loops through the vector 'sizes'
    for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); i++ ){
        // divides the current size by PAGE_SIZE to get the var 'pages'
        int pages = sizes.at(i) / PAGE_SIZE;
        // If the current size is not a multiple of PAGE_SIZE, 
        // increases the var 'pages', otherwise lets it unchanged
        if ( sizes.at(i) % PAGE_SIZE ) pages++;
        // Resizes v to page * PAGE_SIZE and prints its size
        v.resize( pages * PAGE_SIZE );
        cout << v.size() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Therefore v.size becomes the ceiling of the initial size

```
the size is 3,  pages becomes 1 and the vector has a size of 4
the size is 6,  pages becomes 2 and the vector has a size of 8
the size is 8,  pages becomes 2 and the vector has a size of 8
the size is 11, pages becomes 3 and the vector has a size of 12
the size is 0,  pages becomes 0 and the vector has a size of 0
the size is 15, pages becomes 4 and the vector has a size of 16
the size is 9,  pages becomes 3 and the vector has a size of 12
```